# make postfix bypass amavis completely for specific domains

Tags: email, postfix, amavis

I want the postfix agent to bybass the amavis scanner for all mails from and to a specific domain.

So, i added the following line to `/etc/postfix/main.cf`

```
header_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/whitelist.pcre
```

and in the `/etc/postfix/whitelist.pcre` file i have a single line

```
info@xxxxxxxxx.yyy FILTER  SMTP:[127.0.0.1]:10025
```

where `SMTP:[127.0.0.1]:10025` is (AT LEAST I THINK IT IS!) the transport everything returns to after amavis, so emails are delivered.

The problem is (obviously) with the pcre file, because on the error log i get the following error:

> postfix/cleanup[10870]: warning: pcre map /etc/postfix/whitelist.pcre, line 1: ignoring unrecognized request

Answer (score 1):

See [man 5 pcre_table](http://www.postfix.org/pcre_table.5.html) especially in **TABLE FORMAT** section. Also, check [man 5 header_checks](http://www.postfix.org/header_checks.5.html) to get right behavior of `header_checks` feature.

Your PCRE syntax is wrong. It should wrapped in `/.../`. And you must escape [some special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/400316/3604386). For example

```
/info@example\.com/ FILTER  smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is easier to do the following:

Include in /etc/postfix/main.cf

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
#
    check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/exempt_senders,
    check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10023,
```

The file /etc/postfix/exempt/senders contains:

```
someone@somedomain.com FILTER smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025
anotherdomain.com FILTER smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025
```

then a

```
postmap /etc/postfix/exempt_senders
```

reload or restart postfix